# Keeping data retains in the dictionary after the dictionary creates in page load

Tags: asp.net

Mine is an asp.net vb application. I need a dictionary of around 100 keys and values. That dictionary I'd like to initialize when page loads. But I've to use those values and keys in that dictionary in various button events on that page. So how can I achieve that with a 1 time initialization of that values to the dictionary when page loads, since that values in that dictionary clears out normally in every server requests .

Answer (score 0):

Keep the dictionary in session/viewstate after it initialized with keys and values. Typecast the session/viewstate object to dictionary on every server requests.

Comment: That was in my plan. But that dictionary may be little huge. That prevented me from doing so. If no scope I will consider that session method. But I heard about some static object approach. dont know how that will help...

Comment: If the dictionary values are global and not instance based, you can declare the Dictionary as static and can be accessed in all server requests. But the the changes in dictionary will reflect to all the users who are accessing the page.